# ¿Si una función recibe un valor de otra función, esa función será igual al valor de la otra función?

Tags: c++, funciones

Si, lo sé, el **título** de la pregunta es muy confuso... Pongamos de ejemplo un **código**:

```
int prueba2(){
    return 120;
}

int prueba(){
    prueba2();
}
```

**Antes de que lo digas, sí, ese código tiene un comportamiento indefinido, lo sé.**

Ahora aquí va la pregunta:

La función `prueba`, ¿Será igual al valor que retornó la función `prueba2`?, es decir, ¿`prueba` será igual al valor `120`?

**Aunque el código tenga esta forma (Es decir, sin comportamiento indefinido):**

```
int prueba2(){
    return 120;
}

int prueba(){
    return prueba2();
}
```

Sigo con la misma **duda**...

**Hay que aclarar que:**
Esta pregunta es una muy parecida a una que eliminé, porque fue muy mal recibida, y sé la razón de eso... Espero que esta pregunta, sea lo contrario de la otra, es decir, que sea bien recibida.

¡Gracias!

PD: Estoy muy perdido con las funciones y llevo más de 3 meses intentando comprenderlas e investigarlas.

Comment: Existen dos tipos de operaciones las funciones y los procedimientos. Las funciones siempre devuelven un resultado, si no se hace da error,  por otra parte los procedimientos no devuelven ningún redultado

Comment: El titulo de la pregunta es confusa.. Es decir, la funcion de ejemplo que propones no recibe ningun valor, sino, retorna un valor (porque a la funcion no le entra datos, por eso el termino "recibe" no es el adecuado). Si no agregas un `return` a una funcion que si retorna un valor, entonces, el compilador esta en la capacidad de asumir que la ultima instruccion es lo que debe "devolver". De igual manera, el compilador como minimo deberia avisarte que el codigo esta mal, en g++ no olvides de activar los warning con `-Wall -Wextra`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> La función prueba, ¿Será igual al valor que retornó la función prueba2?, es decir, ¿prueba será igual al valor 120?

El TLDR es: ***NO***. Pero si da lugar a bajar un poco mas y entender que es lo que sucede en realidad con nuestro codigo. Te dejo el TLDR, y si quieres entrarle un poco mas lo que sigue es mi respuesta.

Si pero no. Es un poco mas complicado. Para esto vamos a bajar un poco el nivel, de C++ a asembler. Voy a procurar mantenerlo lo mas simple posible.

Pegamos tu codigo (el segundo) en [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/), y nos da como resultado el siguiente ensamblador:

```
prueba2():                            # @prueba2()
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
prueba():                             # @prueba()
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
```

Solo como una micro guia para entenderlo (Porfavor, los que sean mas duchos en assembler no se enojen):

- `mov` significa que va a  mover valores
- Lo que esta de el lado izquierdo recive lo que tiene el del lado derecho
- `eax` es un registro (Una memoria en el microprocesador). Asi tienes 8: eax, ebx, ecx, etc.
- `eax` es el registro en el que se ponen los datos a los que retorna la funcion.

Ya con eso vamos a entrarle a la pregunta:

#### ¿Prueba será igual al valor 120?

Regreso al si pero no. Tecnicamente no, ya que prueba es una funcion, no va a tener el valor de 120. Pero lo que si es que como es una funcion simple, el compilador se toma la tarea de sustituir lo que retorna en el lugar de la funcion, ya que eso es mas rapido que estarla llamando.

Si el compilador no hiciera esas cosas el codigo quedaria asi:

```
#Codigo 1
prueba2():                            # @prueba2()
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 120
        pop     rbp
        ret
prueba():                             # @prueba()
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    prueba2()
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

`prueba2` retorna el valor de 120, y `prueba` llama a esa funcion. Pero al fin y al cabo, si siempre retorna el valor de 120, no hay motivos para hacer una llamada a una funcion. Puede colocar el valor directamente.

Si le colocamos las optimizares al compilador llegamos a esto:

```
#Codigo 2
prueba2():                            # @prueba2()
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
prueba():                             # @prueba()
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
```

Como te fijas, coloca el valor de 120 directamente en el lugar de la llamada a la funcion.

Estas son las optimizaciones que hace el compilador. El codigo 1 lo hace sin optimizaciones, y el codigo 2 lo hace con las optimizaciones al maximo.

#### Conclucion

La respuesta es no. La funcion no tiene el valor literal de 120. Pero el compilador es inteligente, y sabe que puede hacer esas sustituciones directamente en el ensablador. Asi que si activas las optimizaciones, podrias estar utilizando la funcion `prueba` como si hubieras declarado una variable `int prueba=120`, con la exepcion que en forma de funcion añadimos los `()` y que no puedes modificar el valor. Ya con esas restricciones pierde el sentido intentarlo.

#### Extra

Si quieres ayudar al compilador a que sustituya esos valores que ya se conocen en tiempo de compilacion, puedes usar la palabra clave `constexpr`. Por ejemplo, este codigo:

```
int prueba2(){
    return 120;
}

int prueba(){
    return prueba2();
}

int main() {
    return prueba();
}
```

Sin optimizaciones, y sin nada nos da este ensablador:

```
prueba2():                            # @prueba2()
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 120
        pop     rbp
        ret
prueba():                             # @prueba()
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    prueba2()
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
        call    prueba()
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Pero si ya le ponemos las optimizaciones, y creamos las expresiones en tiempo de compilacion:

```
constexpr int prueba2(){
    return 120;
}

constexpr int prueba(){
    return prueba2();
}

int main() {
    return prueba();
}
```

Llegamos a este resultado:

```
main:                                   # @main
        mov     eax, 120
        ret
```

Mucho mejor. Directamente nos saltamos toda la basura y solo retornamos el valor de 120

Si le quieres entrar a ver que es lo que hace tu codigo ya bajando un poco el nivel, te recomiendo esta charla: [CppCon 2017: Matt Godbolt “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4). 10/10 en explicacion.

#### Nota

Con respecto a este codigo:

```
int prueba2(){
    return 120;
}

int prueba(){
    prueba2();
}
```

El codigo compila y corre con `gcc`, no lo haces claro, pero el compilador entendera que quieres retornar `prueba2`. No te recomiendo que hagas esto. No se si esta permitido por el estandar, pero lo que si te puedo asegurar es que puede ser confuso, y lo que menos quieres para tu codigo es que sea confuso.

Comment: +1 por explicar el *porque*

Comment: Me refiero en la declaración de la función, si será igual al valor 120. En la declaración de la función, ¿Será igual al valor 120?

Comment: En tal caso quedate con el TLDR. Al declarar la funcion, haces eso, declarar una funcion. No estas asignando memoria para que almacene el valor 120.

Comment: Mm ya entiendo. Tendré que desaprender, para comprender mejor las funciones.

Comment: @ElblackNinja En tu ejemplo no has **declarado** ninguna función, mas bien, la has **definido** (son dos términos diferentes, declarar no es lo mismo que definir). Y no, la función no será igual al valor `120`, porque una función no es una variable, no es un contenedor donde puedes guardar un valor.  La función `prueba` retornará un valor y será `120` (claro, como lo explica Pablo, si activas las optimizaciones del compilador, reemplazará la **expresión constante** en el `return` para evitar llamar a una función).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Bueno, es que siempre he confundido declarar funciones con definir funciones, pero gracias por el dato :]